# select all data to a database between results = 1 to 100

Tags: php

I have a problem selecting data to a table and echoing e.g.

```
--------------------------------------
id   |   bought   |   customerName    | 
--------------------------------------
1    |     70     |  customer 1       |
2    |     20     |  customer 2       |
3    |     50     |  customer 3       |
4    |     30     |  customer 4       |
5    |     80     |  customer 5       |
6    |    100     |  customer 6       |
--------------------------------------
```

what I want to do is order by bought and select bought between 50 to 100 that would be resulting

```
customer 3 --- 50
customer 1 --- 70
customer 5 --- 80
customer 6 --- 100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this to select data

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE bought BETWEEN 50 AND 100 ORDER BY bought ASC"
```

Comment: im sorry Sheikh my connection has a problem. how about this what is wrong with query? SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE bought BETWEEN 50 AND 100 ORDER BY bought ASC AND cutomerName LIKE David AND user_id = 2

Comment: @IanEscasa, Keep order by at last, thanks :-)

Comment: @IanEscasa, `"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE bought BETWEEN 50 AND 100 AND cutomerName LIKE '%David%' AND user_id = 2 ORDER BY bought ASC"`

Answer (score 0):

try this

> SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE bought BETWEEN 50 AND 100 ORDER BY bought ASC

Comment: how about this what is wrong with query? SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE bought BETWEEN 50 AND 100 ORDER BY bought ASC AND cutomerName LIKE David AND user_id = 2

Comment: cutomerName is not a column in your table above, what do you want from the query to do ?